# Set Default Element in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a custom style set up called 'Paragraph', which (obviously) creates a  `p` element for the user to enter text into.

When first entering the CKEditor area, no style is set and the user is entering text inside no specific element.  Eg the location bar at the bottom just reads `body`

Is there a way I can make the editor default to having a p element so that when the user first enters the editor area, they are in `body > p`?

I've spent a while checking the documentation, and can see how to set the default font and font size, but that isn't what I want.

**EDIT**
Here is the **styles.js** file I have customised to provide the styles:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'default', [
/* Block Styles */

// These styles are already available in the "Format" combo ("format" plugin),
// so they are not needed here by default. You may enable them to avoid
// placing the "Format" combo in the toolbar, maintaining the same features.

{ name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p' },

{ name: 'Heading 1',        element: 'h1' },
{ name: 'Heading 2',        element: 'h2' },
{ name: 'Heading 3',        element: 'h3' },
{ name: 'Heading 4',        element: 'h4' },
{ name: 'Heading 5',        element: 'h5' },
{ name: 'Heading 6',        element: 'h6' }

]);
```

And here is the **config.js** file

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

// To disable CKEditor ACF
config.allowedContent = true;
config.uiColor = '#ffffff';
config.dialog_backgroundCoverColor = '#888888';
config.skin = 'moono';
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
config.entities_latin = false;
config.protectedSource.push(/<script[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi);   // <SCRIPT> tags.

config.toolbar_Full = config.toolbar_Default =
[
    ['Source', '-'],
    ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt', '-'],
    ['Undo', 'Redo', 'Find', 'Replace', 'RemoveFormat', '-'],
    //['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-'],
    //['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote','CreateDiv', '-'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Outdent', 'CreateDiv', 'Blockquote', '-'],
    //['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-'],
    ['InsertLink', 'Unlink', 'Anchor', '-'],
    //['InsertImageOrMedia', 'QuicklyInsertImage', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', '-'],
    ['InsertImageOrMedia', 'Table', 'SpecialChar', '-'],
    //['InsertForms', 'InsertPolls', 'InsertRating', 'InsertYouTubeVideo', 'InsertWidget', '-'],
    ['InsertForms', 'InsertYouTubeVideo', 'InsertWidget', '-'],
    //['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'],
    ['Styles', '-'],
    //['TextColor', 'BGColor', '-'],
    //['InsertMacro', '-'],
    ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']
];

config.toolbar = config.toolbar_Full;

config.scayt_customerid = '***';};
```

And here is a screenshot of what happens on first entering the area: [image: screenshot of what happens on first entering the area]

Comment: .. what? How do you manage that? I have never seen text directly entered into the body before, I didn't even know that it was possible! Can you link to your config file and possible customizations?

Comment: epic!  added the info into the question - thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, interesting config. If you try to change `config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;` does that change the issue? If yes, I suggest that every time that you clear the contents you input a placeholder "<p></p>" that counts as the empty content. If that works I'll add it as an answer but I won't yet because I'm not sure.

Comment: thanks Nenotlep - I'll have a look this afternoon and let you know.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That's worked perfectly - thanks!  If you submit it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the culprit in this case is `config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;`

The workaround here is to insert `<p></p>` as the default contents of the editor so that it's not actually empty when it's initialized or cleared. The cursor should automatically plop inside the paragraph.

Comment: Let me remind that setting `config.enterMode` to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` is not recommended :). The best and cleanest content is produced in the `ENTER_P` mode.